# CSS3 column layout divide one element into two parts

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle problem demo: https://jsfiddle.net/icewind/w3ugftup/

```css
.col-wrapper {
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #444;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-column-width: 220px;
}
.remark{
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
.remark:after{
    content: '.';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -17px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-wrapper">
    <p>In our urban and suburban houses what should we do without cats? In our sitting or bedrooms, our libraries, in our kitchens and storerooms, our farms, barns, and rickyards, in our docks, our granaries, our ships, and our wharves, in our corn markets, meat markets, and other places too numerous to mention, how useful they are! In our ships, however, the rats oft set them at defiance; still they are of great service.</p>
    <p>How wonderfully patient is the cat when watching for rats or mice, awaiting their egress from their place of refuge or that which is their home! How well Shakespeare in Pericles, Act iii., describes this keen attention of the cat to its natural pursuit!</p>
    <p>A slight rustle, and the fugitive comes forth; a quick, sharp, resolute motion, and the cat has proved its usefulness. Let any one have a plague of rats and mice, as I <span class="remark">once</span> had, and let them be delivered therefrom by cats, as I was, and they will have a lasting and kind regard for them.</p>
    <p>A friend not long since informed me that a cat at Stone's Distillery was seen to catch two rats at one time, a fore foot on each. All the cats kept at this establishment, and there are several, are of the red tabby colour, and therefore most likely all males.</p>
</div>
```

When I use css3 column layout like the demo,and I add a bookmark to a word which happened to be at the bottom of a column, sometimes the bookmark icon get divided into two parts by the columb layout.

I tried to use 'break-inside: avoid;' and 'break-before: avoid;' css rules but it seems not work.

Is there any solution about my problem?

Comment: You want to remove the red mark? Or what? Explain further.

Comment: Are you trying to add a footnote? Doubtful if `columns` would support that.

Comment: I don't want to remove the red mark, I just want to avoid the red mark from getting divided into two parts by the column.

Answer (score 1):

> **Unfortunately word 'once' is not on the same line but this is the only way I know. rally is not easy just take a look.**

1. Well, in **Html** `&nbsp` like so `<span class="remark">once&nbsp</span>`
2. For **Css** in `.col-wrapper` you add `-webkit-column-width: 220px; -moz-column-width: 150px; column-width: 150px;` for **browsers compatibility** and change **padding** to `padding:15px 27px 15px 27px;`.
3. In remark:after{} change and add this codes {
   `bottom: -7px;` `left: 1%;` `width: 33px;` `height: 10px;`
   **`background: url("http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/dept-icons/camera-icon.gif") no-repeat center bottom;}`**
4. Add `.col-wrapper > p {line-height: 19.5px;}
   .remark { background-color: yellow;  position: relative; bottom: 4px;}`

```css
.col-wrapper {

  background-color: #efefef;

  color: #444;

  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-column-width: 220px;

  -moz-column-width: 150px;

  column-width: 150px;

  padding: 15px 27px 15px 27px;

}

.remark:after {

  content: '.';

  bottom: -7px;

  left: 1%;

  width: 33px;

  height: 10px;

  position: absolute;

  background: url('http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/dept-icons/camera-icon.gif') no-repeat center bottom;

}

.col-wrapper > p {

  line-height: 19.5px;

}

.remark {

  background-color: yellow;

  position: relative;

  bottom: 4px;

}
```

```html
<div class="col-wrapper">
  <p>In our urban and suburban houses what should we do without cats? In our sitting or bedrooms, our libraries, in our kitchens and storerooms, our farms, barns, and rickyards, in our docks, our granaries, our ships, and our wharves, in our corn markets,
    meat markets, and other places too numerous to mention, how useful they are! In our ships, however, the rats oft set them at defiance; still they are of great service.</p>
  <p>How wonderfully patient is the cat when watching for rats or mice, awaiting their egress from their place of refuge or that which is their home! How well Shakespeare in Pericles, Act iii., describes this keen attention of the cat to its natural pursuit!</p>
  <p>A slight rustle, and the fugitive comes forth; a quick, sharp, resolute motion, and the cat has proved its usefulness. Let any one have a plague of rats and mice, as I <span class="remark">once&nbsp</span>had, and let them be delivered therefrom by cats,
    as I was, and they will have a lasting and kind regard for them.</p>
  <p>A friend not long since informed me that a cat at Stone's Distillery was seen to catch two rats at one time, a fore foot on each. All the cats kept at this establishment, and there are several, are of the red tabby colour, and therefore most likely
    all males.</p>
</div>
```

> **You might need to change some pixels according to your small icon.** If you have any question let me know.

Comment: Eh, that makes the remark icon display inline and not the position I wanted it to be.

Comment: so you want it to be block not inline? (clarification)

Comment: Yeah, that is a expected view created by the designer. And I tried to make the web pages like the design as much as possible.

Comment: but that will cover the word under it because height light (once) and red box below that. (I'm working on it).

Comment: In real case I use a small image instead of the red box and it will not cover the word below that much, and in the demo I use a red box to make the demo easy and clear.

Comment: your welcome, is not working for you? because you didn't vote up my answer!! if you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Oh, I would like to vote up your answer very much, but, as a new user here, I don't have enough reputation to vote. I will do it as soon as I got enough reputation.^ ^

Answer (score 0):

this is really interesting CSS issue. Im working on the solution meanwhile I suggest you a workaround solution for time being. Instead of showing the bookmark on the bottom, I moved to the top.

```
.remark:after{
    content: '.';
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that could be a solution, but, when the bookmark shows on the top of a column, a similar problem comes again. - -!